# Connecting a libp2p node to the Substrate Parachain Network

Tags: substrate-node-template, parachain, substrate-node, rococo, nodes

## Goal

Add a libp2p node to the Substrate parachain network to have Idle 0 peers to 1 peer.

### Method

I'm using mdns as the discovery mechanism.

Libp2p Config:

> const options = {
>
> > peerId: peerId,
> > addresses: {
> > listen: ['/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/0/ws'],
> > },
> > transports: [
> > tcp(),
> > webSockets(),
> > ],
> > streamMuxers: [yamux(), mplex()],
> > connectionEncryption: [noise()],
> > peerDiscovery: [
> > mdns(),
> > ],
> > services: {
> > identify: identify({
> > agentVersion: 'Polkadot parachain/v1.6.0-unknown',
> > }),
> > ping: ping({
> > protocolPrefix: 'ipfs',
> > interval: 10000,
> > timeout: 10000,
> > }),
> > },
> > config: {
> > peerDiscovery: {
> > autoDial: true,
> > mdns: {
> > interval: 5000,
> > enabled: true,
> > ip: '127.0.0.1',
> > broadcast: true,
> > },
> > },
> > },
> > }

My libp2p node is started, but it doesn't seem to discover on the Substrate parachain.

### Question

I've configured the libp2p node to be discoverable on the parachain network, but I can't seem to connect for some reason. Is there a step that I'm missing?